# How to create a file with terrafom and include variable as literal?

Tags: variables, ansible, interpolation, terraform, postfix-mta

Using terraform v0.12.9 and building a file using template_file data source, I could not use double dollar signs **$$** to treat input **${data_directory}** as literals.

Looking for solution to sort out this in a right way or looking for any other suggestion or workaround that can help to create a file with this content.

I have tried to use double dollar sign (like in a code example below) to isolate this **${data_directory}** as literals in a file output.

Here is a code that I'm trying to use to create postfix main.cf file with terraform:

```
variable "hostname" {
  default = "test"
}

variable "domain_name" {
  default = "test.com"
}

variable "fn_main_cf" {
  default = "main.cf"
}

data "template_file" "main_cf" {
  template = <<EOF
##
## Network settings
##
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1, ::1, 120.121.123.124, 2a03:b0a0:3:d0::5e79:4001
myhostname = ${var.hostname}.${var.domain_name}

###
### Outbound SMTP connections (Postfix as sender)
###
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:$${data_directory}/smtp_scache
EOF
}

  data "template_cloudinit_config" "main_cf" {
    gzip          = false
    base64_encode = false

    part {
      filename     = "${var.fn_main_cf}"
      content_type = "text/cloud-config"
      content      = "${data.template_file.main_cf.rendered}"
    }
  }

  resource "null_resource" "main_cf" {
    triggers = {
      template = "${data.template_file.main_cf.rendered}"
    }

    provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "echo \"${data.template_file.main_cf.rendered}\" > ~/projects/mail-server/files/etc/postfix/${var.fn_main_cf}"
    }

}
```

As you can see there is a lot of variables and all this is working fine, but ${data_directory} should not be treated as variable but just as literals and should stay as it is in output file on a disk.

Expected output in the **main.cf** created file saved on a disk should be like following:

```
##
## Network settings
##
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1, ::1, 120.121.123.124, 2a03:b0a0:3:d0::5e79:4001 
myhostname = test.test.com

###
### Outbound SMTP connections (Postfix as sender)
###
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
```

So **${data_directory}** should not be treated by terraform as a terraform variable but just as group of characters, literals (a regular text input).

Running **terraform plan** the output with double dollar signs **$$** is following:

```
Error: failed to render : <template_file>:11,43-57: Unknown variable; There is no variable named "data_directory".
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`template_file` remains available in Terraform primarily for Terraform 0.11 users. In Terraform 0.12 there is no need to use `template_file`, because it has been replaced with two other features:

- For templates in separate files, [the built in `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) can render an external template from directly in the language, without the need for a separate provider and data source.
- For inline templates (specified directly within the configuration) you can just write them in directly where they need to be, or factor them out via [Local Values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html).

The `local_file` resource is also a better way to create a local file on disk than to use a `local-exec` provisioner. By using `template_file` and `local-exec` here you're forcing yourself to contend with two levels of additional escaping: Terraform template escaping to get the literal template into the `template_file` data source, and then shell escaping inside your provisioner.

Here's a more direct way to represent your template and your file:

```
variable "postfix_config_path" {
  # Note that for my example this is expected to be the full path
  # to the file, not just the filename. Terraform idiom is to be
  # explicit about this sort of thing, rather than relying on
  # environment variables like HOME.
  type = string
}

locals {
  postfix_config = <<-EOT
    ##
    ## Network settings
    ##
    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
    inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1, ::1, 120.121.123.124, 2a03:b0a0:3:d0::5e79:4001
    myhostname = ${var.hostname}.${var.domain_name}

    ###
    ### Outbound SMTP connections (Postfix as sender)
    ###
    smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:$${data_directory}/smtp_scache
  EOT
}

resource "local_file" "postfix_config" {
  filename = var.postfix_config_path
  content  = local.postfix_config
}
```

---

As the `local` provider documentation warns, Terraform isn't really designed for directly managing files and other resources on a local machine. The `local` provider is there for unusual situations, and this might be one of those situations, in which case the above is a reasonable way to address it.

Note though that a more standard Terraform usage pattern would be for Terraform to be used to start up a new virtual machine that will run Postfix and pass in the necessary configuration via a vendor-specific `user_data` or `metadata` argument.

If the postfix server is managed separately from this Terraform configuration, then an alternative pattern is to arrange for Terraform to write the necessary data to a shared configuration store (e.g. AWS SSM Parameter Store, or HashiCorp Consul) and then use separate software on the postfix server to read that and update the `main.cf` file. For HashiCorp Consul, that separate software might be [consul-template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template). Similar software exists for other parameter stores, allowing you to decouple the configuration of individual virtual machines from the configuration of your overall infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you Martin, great explanation and a guidance how to use Terraform in the right way. :-) Thank you also for explanation about AWS SSM Parameter Store and HashiCorp Consul, I was not aware about those services. I appreciate it very much.